# C#: How to reflect a class to get its properties of pre defined data type

Tags: c#

I have a class 'Employee', it has following members:

```
//[membername,type]
[Name,string]
[DOB,DateTime]
[DateOfHire,DateTime]
[TerminationDate,DateTime?]
[AddressChanges,List<string>]
```

Here, I need to reflect and get all the properties except the ones that are of collection type.

In this example,except AddressChanges, I need to get all the members.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending what you mean by 'collection', something like this will work:

```
var notCollectionProperties =
    typeof(Employee)
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(prop => !typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType));
```

More generally you might want to use `IEnumerable` rather than `ICollection`.

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection to enumerate the properties and exclude those with a collection type. For example:

```
Type myType = typeof(TargetClass);
foreach(PropertyInfo propertyInfo in myType.GetProperties())
{
    if(propertyInfo.PropertyType is ...)
    {
        // Handle cases 
    }    
}
```